# Getting string value as output parameter on successful execution of query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON

GO

ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[UserLogin]

@Mode VARCHAR(20) = '',
@UserLoginName VARCHAR(500) = '',
@UserPassword VARCHAR(50) = '',
@Params VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT

AS
BEGIN
    IF (@mode = 'User_Login')
    BEGIN 
        IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM UserMst WHERE UserLoginName = @UserLoginName AND UserPassword = @UserPassword)
        BEGIN
            SET @Params = 'Success';
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SET @Params = 'Failure';
        END
    END

    RETURN;
END
```

I am using a stored procedure to verify the login credentials. If the credentials are valid then the stored procedure should return a string parameter as an output as success and in case of invalid credentials the stored procedure should return the string parameter as failure accordingly.

Comment: prefixing `Sp_` is not advisable. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Are you facing any issue or any error is ouccred while executing the SP? Kindly mention exact message which you want?

Comment: No I was not facing any error but I am not able to return the String parameter as output @Mittal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your `RETURN` statement at the end with a select like this

```
SELECT Result = @Params
```

Because `RETURN` is used for functions and to output a value from stored procedure, we usually use `SELECT` statements

Comment: Thank U so much for the great help @jayasurya